# Trouble showing || in TeXstudio

Tags: math-mode, texstudio

I've just installed TeXstudio and I have two troubles with my first attempt:

This is the code:

```
Since the size of subgroups divides the size of group, |H| \le \frac{|G|}{2} .\\ Hence \mathbf{P}(h \in H)\le \frac{1}{2} \: so  \mathbf{P}(h \notin H) \ge \frac{1}{2}.
```

And this is how it has been shown:

[image]

and I want to fix these two mistakes:

1) `|H|` converted to `-H-`, surprisingly!

2) `Hence` and `so` are Italic! In fact they has been considered as a part of formula but I do not want so!

Can anyone help me to fix them?

**Edit** (Due to CarLaTeX's kind answer)

I have copied your code and here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you post a full compilable code? Commands like `\frac` and `\le` are meant to be used in math environment. Judging from the output, it doesn't seem like you enclosed the whole thing in `\( \)` as well, so what is your code exactly?

Comment: @Troy -- i think the "Hence" is treated as math because the `\le` would have gotten an error message (since it requires math mode) and tex would have inserted a `$` sign.

Answer (score 5):

As Troy said, formulae should be within `\(...\)`, if inline math, or within `\[...\]`, if display math.

The following works perfectly in TeXstudio.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document} 
Since the size of subgroups divides the size of group, \(|H| \le \frac{|G|}{2}\).

Hence \(\mathbf{P}(h \in H)\le \frac{1}{2} \:\) so  \(\mathbf{P}(h \notin H) \ge \frac{1}{2}\).
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit: answer to the OP's comment.*

"Hence" is **not** pushed forward, as you can see from the enlarged image, where I added a red line to show the alignment.

It may look so due to the `H` shape, but it is not.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But "Hence" is pushed a little bit forward! How can I fix it?

Comment: @LeilaHatami "Hence" is already correctly aligned, see the edit of my answer.

Comment: Thank you. But It's not for me. see the new photo I've added to the question please.

Comment: @LeilaHatami -- did you by chance insert a blank line before the line starting with "Hence"?  (that sometimes happens when cutting and pasting.)

Comment: It's probably due to a paragraph indent?

Comment: @LeilaHatami Your paragraph is indented, if Barbara's comment doesn't solve your problem, please add a COMPLETE [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), otherwise it's impossible to help you!

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yeah! It was happened! but I want it in a new line! Is there any way except using "\\"?

Comment: @LeilaHatami -- well, `\\ ` will break the line and extend the broken line to the right margin.  `\newline` will break the line and leave it at its "natural" length.  and a blank line will start a new paragraph, but you can reverse the indentation with `\noindent`.  there may be some other more esoteric methods, but nothing an inexperienced user wants to use.  (the primitive `\break` acts like `\\ ` except that it doesn't look for a `[` to adjust the vertical spacing; someone working in latex almost *never* wants to use `\break`.)